# Pasar un Fichero como Parámetro en C

Tags: c

Estaba realizando ejercicios en C de cara al examen y me he encontrado con este enunciado:

> Cita en bloque Realiza un programa en C que utilice una función que escriba el número de
>   caracteres, palabras y líneas que tiene un fichero de texto “texto.txt” que recibe como
>   parámetro.

Mi problema viene a la hora de pasar ese fichero como parámetro, que no sé muy bien como hacerlo. He intentado hacerlo mediante una función aparte (está puesta en modo de comentarios), y desde el main, pero en ninguno me funciona. Alguna idea?

```
#include <stdio.h> // Incluimos las librerías necesarias
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Declaramos los prototipos ncesarios
FILE *abrir_fichero ( FILE *texto ) ;
void mostrar_resultados ( FILE *texto ) ;
int contar_caracteres ( FILE *texto ) ;
int contar_palabras ( FILE *texto ) ;
int contar_lineas ( FILE *texto ) ;

int main () {

    system ("cls") ;

    FILE *texto_parametro ;

    texto_parametro = fopen ( "texto.txt" , "r" ) ;

    if ( fopen == NULL ) {

        printf("Mal");

    }

    else {

        mostrar_resultados ( texto_parametro ) ;

    }

    fclose ( texto_parametro ) ; // Cerramos el fichero con el que hemos trabajado 

    return 0 ;

}

/*
// FILE *abrir_fichero ( FILE *texto )
// {P} Fichero *texto inicializado
// {Q} Abre el fichero y lo devuelve como parámetro
FILE *abrir_fichero ( FILE *texto  ){

    texto = fopen ( "texto.txt" , "r" ) ;

    if ( fopen == NULL ) {

        printf("\nError en la Apertura\n");

    }

    else {

        mostrar_resultados (texto) ;
        return texto ;

    }

}
 */
// void mostrar_resultados ( FILE *texto ) 
// {P} Fichero *Texto abierto e inicializado
// {Q} Muestra en pantalla el número de líneas, carácteres y palabras
void mostrar_resultados ( FILE *texto ) {

    // Mostramos en pantalla los resultados
    printf("\nTu texto tiene:\n\t%i Caracteres\n\t%i Palabras\n\t%i Lineas\n" , contar_caracteres( texto ) , contar_palabras ( texto ) , contar_lineas ( texto ) );

}
// int contar_caracteres ( FILE *texto ) 
// {P} Fichero *texto abierto e inicializado
// {Q} Devuelve el número de carácteres del fichero
int contar_caracteres ( FILE *texto ) {

    int contador = 0 ; // Inicializamos contador a 0

    while ( !feof (texto) ) { // Leemos caracter por caracter hasta final de fichero y

        contador++ ; // Aumentamos el contador

    }

    return contador ; // Devolvemos el contador
}
// int contar_palabras ( FILE *texto ) 
// {P} Fichero *texto abierto e inicializado
// {Q} Devuelve el número de palabras del fichero
int contar_palabras ( FILE *texto ) {

    int contador = 0 ; // Inicializamos el contador

    while ( getc (texto) != EOF ) { // Leemos hasta final de archivo

        if ( getc(texto) == ' ' ) { // Si hay espacio en blanco

            contador++ ; // Aumentamos el contador

        }

    }

    return contador ; // Devolvemos el contador

}

// int contar_líneas ( FILE *texto ) 
// {P} Fichero *texto abierto e inicializado
// {Q} Devuelve el número de líneas del fichero
int contar_lineas ( FILE *texto ) {

    int contador = 0 ; // Inicializamos contador a 0

    while ( getc (texto) != EOF ) { // Leemos hasta fin de fichero

        if ( getc(texto) == '\n' ) { // Si el carácter es un salto de línea

            contador++ ; // Aumentamos en 1 el contador

        }

    }

    return contador ; // Devolvemos el contador
```

Gracias! :)

Answer (score 2):

El problema con tu implementación actual es que llamas tantas veces a la función `getc` que el archivo llega a EOF antes de terminar con su tarea.

Lo correcto sería almacenar el resultado de `getc` en una variable y compararlo luego, posteriormente devolver el estado del archivo al inicio para dejarlo completamente disponible para la proxima llamada que se ejecutará sobre el mismo archivo.

Teniendo en cuenta lo mencionado anteriormente, tu problema puede resolverse de la siguiente manera utilizando la función `rewind` o `fseek`:

```
int contar_caracteres(FILE *texto) {
  int contador = 0;
  while (!feof(texto))
    ++contador;
  rewind(texto);
  return contador;
}

int contar_palabras(FILE *texto) {
  int contador = 0, caracter = 0;
  while ((caracter = getc(texto)) != EOF) [
    if (caracter == ' ') // Evitamos avanzar el buffer.
      contador++;
  }
  rewind(texto);
  return contador;
}

int contar_lineas(FILE *texto) {
  int contador = 0, caracter = 0;
  while ((caracter = getc(texto)) != EOF) {
    if (caracter == '\n')
      contador++;
  }
  rewind(texto);
  return contador;
}
```

Esto es todo si solo quieres resolver tu pregunta, te dejo algunos enlaces de referencia:

- [Documentación de `fseek`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html).
- [Documentación de `rewind`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rewind)

---

En casos como este me gusta compartir un fragmento de código que siempre uso para leer archivos en disco:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

char *readfile(const char *filename) {
  if (!filename)
    return fprintf(stderr, "Error: @filename es NULL.\n"), NULL;
  /* Verificamos si el archivo existe y no está vacio, tambien si no es un directorio. */
  struct stat s;
  if ((-1 == stat(filename, &s)) || S_ISDIR(s.st_mode) || !s.st_size)
    return fprintf(stderr, "Error: Archivo no existe o es un directorio.\n"), NULL;

  FILE *in = fopen(filename, "rb"); /* Abrimos el archivo para leer. */
  if (!in)
    return fprintf(stderr, "Error: No se pudo abrir el archivo.\n"), NULL;

  /* Colocamos el tamaño del archivo + 1 byte (vacio) */
  char *out = calloc(1, s.st_size + 1);
  if (!out) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: No se pudo pedir memoria para el contenido del archivo.\n");
    fclose(in);
    return NULL;
  }

  /* Luego leemos el archivo hasta el final y obtenemos una cadena con todo el contenido. */
  (void)fread(out, s.st_size, 1, in);
  return out;
}
```

Trabajar con archivos siempre es más facil cuando tienes todo el contenido del mismo dentro de un `string` o `char *`, la idea detrás de esta función es que puedas implementar todo lo demás sin tener que utilizar el archivo directamente, ahora puedes implementar las funciones que necesitas alrededor de un ciclo:

```
#include <ctype.h>

int contar_palabras(char *str) {
  int cont = 0;
  while (str && *str) { /* Mientras el caracter no sea el caracter vacio o nulo. */
    if (!isspace(*str)) {
      cont++;
      while (*str && !isspace(*str)) /* Cuenta la palabra si no es un espacio. */
        ++str;
    }
    else 
      ++str;
  }
  return cont; /* Cantidad de palabras. */
}
```

Notar que esta función `contar_palabras` cuenta `_"3432` como una palabra por igual, es decir, que su forma de separar las palabras es a través de los espacios (`\r\n\t`).

Igual puedes crear otra función para contar las lineas de tu archivo:

```
int contar_lineas(char *str) {
  int cont = 0;
  while (str && *str) {
    if (*str == '\n')
      cont++;
    ++str;
  }
  return cont + 1; /* Al iniciar en cero, todo archivo tiene cont + 1 lineas. */
}
```

Y por último, contar la cantidad de caracteres que tiene el archivo, aquí hay un problema, un caracter puede ser cualquier caracter (incluyendo espacios) o solo caracteres imprimibles (letras, numeros, simbolos, etc, etc...), dependiendo de tu definición de "caracter", entonces puedes proceder con una de estas funciones:

```
/* Esta función retornará una cantidad en base al resultado de isprint(*str) */
int contar_caracteres_imprimibles(char *str) {
  int cont = 0;
  while (str && *str) {
    if (isprint(*str)) ++cont;
    ++str;
  }
  return cont;
}
```

O:

```
/* Esto es igual que strlen(str), por diversion :) */
int contar_caracteres(char *str) {
  char *end = str;
  while (end && *end) ++end;
  return (int)(end - str);
}
```

Y al final, todo eso lo enlazas dentro de tu `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char *const argv[]) {
  if (argc < 2)
    return fprintf(stderr, "Uso: %s <archivo>\n", *argv);

  char *contenido = readfile(argv[1]); /* Tratamos de abrir el archivo. */
  if (!contenido)
    return 1;

  /* Ejecutamos las funciones. */
  int lineas = contar_lineas(contenido);
  int palabras = contar_palabras(contenido);
  int imprimibles = contar_caracteres_imprimibles(contenido);
  int caracteres = contar_caracteres(contenido);

  fprintf(stdout, "El archivo: '%s' tiene: %d lineas, %d palabras, "
                  "%d caracteres imprimibles y %d caracteres en total.\n", 
          argv[1], lineas, palabras, imprimibles, caracteres);

  /* la función readfile retorna un puntero colocado con calloc,
     debemos liberar esa memoria al final. */
  free(contenido); 
  return 0;
}
```

Aquí te dejo un [repl.it](https://repl.it/@IamNaCl/PruebaContenidoFicheros) para que pruebes y veas como funciona, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

en lenguaje C, se pueden pasar parámetros o argumentos en la función principal `main`.
Para tal efecto, se deben definir justamente en la implementación:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
...
...
```

donde `argc` es un entero que contiene la cantidad de argumentos pasados en el arreglo `argv`.  Si no se pasan parámetros, `argc` tiene un valor 1 y `argv` tiene su primer vector con el nombre del programa.

En el ejemplo

```
> proceoso.exe archivo.txt 2 4
```

donde argc va a ser 4, y los vectores de argv seran.

```
argv[0] => 'proceso.exe'
argv[1] => 'archivo.txt'
argv[2] => '2'
argv[3] => '4'
```

Aca un implementación (simple)

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    strcpy(nom_fichero,argv[1]);
    valor1 = atoi(argv[2]);
    valor2 = atoi(argv[3]);
...
```

cabe destacar, que `argv` al ser un arreglo de tipo `char`, los valores siempre serán consideramos como `strings`.

Espero te sirva esta explicación.

Comment: `argv` puede ser un puntero a puntero de char (`char **`) o un array de punteros (`char *[]`) o un array de arrays de char (`char [][]`).